# How to verify any of lists of strings are in another array and append the array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of strings in Python:

```
array=array(['Thisis_anapple','Thatis_acat', 'Thoseare_dogs'], dtype=object)
```

I want to append all the strings that have 'cat' or 'dog'. Ideal result is:

```
list=['Thatis_acat','Thoseare_dogs']
```

My code is:

```
list=[]
if any(x in array for x in ['cat', 'dog']):
    list=list.append(x)
print(list)
```

But the result is actually blank list.

Comment: As a general tip, do not use `list` as a variable name, since it will hide the [builtin class name for lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), which is likely to cause you trouble later.

Comment: Which array library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = ['Thisis_anapple','Thatis_acat', 'Thoseare_dogs']
L = ['cat', 'dog']
R = [entry for entry in A if any(l in entry for l in L)]
print(R)
```

This solution involves conditional [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

It basically says make a list R, so that it includes every entry from A if any pattern from L can be found in that entry.

Comment: Thanks very much kszl~!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re`:

```
import re

array = ['Thisis_anapple','Thatis_acat', 'Thoseare_dogs']
words = ['cat', 'dog']
to_find = re.compile('|'.join(words))

result = list(filter(to_find.search, array))
```

This could be done using a list comprehension instead of using filter but it seemed more appropriate:

```
result = [s for s in array if to_find.search(s)]
```

---

Result: *(same for both filter and list comp)*

```
['Thatis_acat', 'Thoseare_dogs']
```